# How could I use MYSQL ROW_NUMBER OVER with MYSQL Server not MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I am trying to calculate weeks of the month such as `[week1, week2, week3, week4]`. it's working fin in my local machine`[Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution]` but my live server is using `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.32, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`.

this what I tried.

```php
if($date == "lastmonth"){
            $date_param = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->format('m');
            $query = " = ".json_encode($date_param);
            $column =  'MONTH(`transactions`.`created_at`)';
            $group_by = DB::raw('week(`transactions`.`created_at`)');
            $select_query = 'CASE WHEN WEEK(`transactions`.`created_at`) THEN CONCAT("week", `row_number() over(order by `transactions`.`created_at`)`) END date';
 }
```

my query:

```php
        $sale_data = DB::table('transactions')
            ->Join('transaction_status','transaction_status.invoice_no','=','transactions.invoice_no')
            ->selectRaw('
                '.$select_query.',
                SUM(CASE WHEN `transactions`.`transaction_type` = 1 THEN `transactions`.`total_amount` END)  AS sale,
                SUM(CASE WHEN `transactions`.`transaction_type` = 1 THEN `transactions`.`max_factor_qty` END) AS max_factor_qty,
                SUM(CASE WHEN `transactions`.`transaction_type` = 2 THEN `transactions`.`total_amount` END)  AS sale_return,
                SUM(CASE WHEN `transactions`.`transaction_type` = 2 THEN `transactions`.`max_factor_qty` END)  AS max_factor_qty_return,
                `transactions`.`transaction_type` AS transaction_type,
                `transaction_status`.`invoice_no` AS invoice_no,
                `transaction_status`.`invoice_type` AS invoice_type,
                `transaction_status`.`payment_status` AS payment_status
            ')
            ->whereRaw($column .$query)
            ->where('transactions.status', 3)
            ->groupBy($group_by)
            ->get();
```

expected result:

```json
performance_group": [
            {
                "name": "week1",
                "amount": 0,
                "qty": 0,
                "return_amount": 234.05,
                "return_qty": 2.04
            },
            {
                "name": "week2",
                "amount": 2207787.1,
                "qty": 18020.98,
                "return_amount": 86379.6,
                "return_qty": 495.71
            },
            {
                "name": "week3",
                "amount": 2444169.39,
                "qty": 18162.57,
                "return_amount": 108859.4,
                "return_qty": 616.52
            },
            
        ]
    }
```

and this is the error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
```

so my question how could I implement this.
any help?

Comment: You need mysql version 8.0 at least..

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for your quick response, is there any other way to achieve the same result without changing the version.

Comment: Did you test and reject the duplicate?